# OCUnitTest Cases documentation

Tags: iphone

i googled for OCUnitTestCase Documentation but dint find too much about it ...
i am planning to create test case for my project. so can any one tell me rough estimation of how much time it will take for whole project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Matt Gallaghers Cocoa With Love post on [iPhone Unit Testing](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/12/sample-iphone-application-with-complete.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is depend on list of functionality you are gonna test. Post the application definition and list of functionality.

Comment: it is having 6 to 7 functionality so could u please tell me how much time it would take functionality like it has one algo to convert barcode digit  into barcode image. and  getting reward point from server etc  waiting for yr reply

Comment: According to my experience it will take 3-4 days to analyze functionality and create the test cases based on functionality.

Comment: if u have any document or code link . please forward to me on pawan.mangal@techendeavour.com

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/tools/unittest.html This link is really good. Using that you can create your test cases. Test Driving Your Code with OCUnit